# How to output to MongoDB collection using Spring Data Aggregation

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I need to use $out option and allowDiskUse from MongoDB in Spring Data.
If I have something like

```
db.ratings.aggregate(
[
    {$group:{_id:"$movieId", users_rated:{$push: "$userId"}}},
    {$out: "movieUsersRated"}
],
{allowDiskUse: true}
);
```

in Java using Spring Data like this

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
            group("movieId").push("$userId").as("users_rated")
    );
```

but I don't know how or where to add $out and allowDiskUse. I've looked at many tutorials but none seem to have these options combined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`allowDiskUse` can be set using `AggregationOptions`. The `$out` operator is not directly supported but can be added by providing an `AggregationOperation` implementation for it.

```java
AggregationOptions options = newAggregationOptions().allowDiskUse(true).build();

Aggregation agg = newAggregation( //
    group("movieId").push("$userId").as("users_rated"), //
    new AggregationOperation() {

      @Override
      public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return new BasicDBObject("$out", "movieUsersRated");
      }
    }).withOptions(options);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I assumed I can use allowDiskUse like that but was wondering is there a way for $out. Again thank you.